# How to set up [ ZeroMQ ] for use in a Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, zeromq

While my primary domain of expertise is not **`Visual Studio 2015`** setup / project configuration, I have experienced troubles on loading / configuring **`ZeroMQ`** project.

How to proceed correctly on loading a `ZeroMQ` Project?

Observed errors:

- current build on github and even old "stable" versions cause **`cmake`** errors
- `ZeroMQ` Installer does not support Visual Studio v14

Instructions would be awesome, as it seems that there is no other source of documentation for this situation on the internet.

Comment: My problem is, that I cannot use ZMQ in VS 2015 (as the title says). And what I did so far doesn't matter as I pointed out the errors that cause this Question. I don't want you to recommend a book or tutorial. I want to avoid these errors and asked if anyone has experienced the same and could help me.

Comment: And btw: if i could describe my problem in detail I would propably be able to fix it myself. However, I don't have a clue and thats why I am asking you (I mean like not YOU in particular, as you don't seem to have the slightest idea)

Comment: No worries. Maybe read this help page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Good luck!

Comment: The Question out of any doubts meets StackOverflow Community primary focus (cit.: "software tools commonly used by programmers" )

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Had the same problem a while ago. Here is what I did to solve this:

### Download the right ZMQ version

The "download link" provided on the ZMQ website seems outdated.
To really get the current version you would have to use Git:

```
git clone https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq.git
```

---

### Build with Visual Studio 2015

The repository comes with a pre-build Visual Studio project. You can find it in `...\libzmq\builds\msvc`. To build for Visual Studio 2015 `cd` into `vs2015` and open `libzmq.sln`.

You can choose if you want to compile static or dynamic libraries: `DynRelease` or `StaticRelease` for either Win32 or x64.

After that, run `Build > Build solution` to compile everything.

---

### Setup project to use compiled libraries

After you created your project, go to the project's properties:

`C++ > General > Additional Include Directories` should point to the include path of the repository. If you want to use C++ style some [additional files](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq) have to be placed in this directory. Alternatively you can take a look at https://github.com/zeromq/zmqpp.

`Linker > General > Additional Library Directories` should point to the built libraries. They should be located at `...\libzmq\bin\x64\Release\v140\dynamic\`.

`Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies` should contain the name of the library you want to use. The default should be `libzmq.lib`, otherwise you will find the name in the `bin` directory.

The program depends on the `libzmq.dll` file you just built. This file has to be placed within your project's build directory. To achieve this, you can add the following command to `Build Events > Post-Build Event > Command Line`:

```
copy /Y "...\libzmq\bin\x64\Release\v140\dynamic\libzmq.dll" "$(OutDir)"
```

This will copy the .dll file to the destination directory on every build if it's missing.

---

Hope this helps =)

Comment: This fails because, for some reason, the build requires libsodium to be present somewhere..